# ruby/sinatra handle the ajax request but nothing happens

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, sinatra

I'm trying to make a simple app using AJAX request for load data in the same page.

Here's the .rb code:

```
get '/' do 
    erb :index
end

post '/ssearch' do
  if request.xhr?

    keyword = params[:key]
    items = extract_cse_info(keyword)

    erb :ssearch, :locals => { 'items' => items }
  else
    erb :index
  end
end
```

Here there's the .js file loaded by layout.erb

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.SR_title').hide();
    $('#msg').hide();

    $('.SR_box').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.SR_title').toggle().stop(true, true);
        $(this).toggleClass('SR_box_hover');
    }); 

    $("#searchform").submit(function(){
            var   form = $("#searchform"),
         term = form.find( "input[name='key']" ).val(),
         url  = form.attr("action"); 
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: term,
            success: function(msg){
            $('#msg').html(msg);
        }
        });

    });
```

And here there's index.erb code

```
<div class="search">
    <form method="POST" action="/ssearch" id="searchform">
        <input id="search" type="search" name="key" autocomplete="on" placeholder="search qui..." />
        <button class="submit" type="submit">Go!</button>
    </form>

    <div id="msg"></div>
</div>
```

and ssearch.erb that execute some stuff.

```
<% i = 1 %>
<% items["items"].each do |x| %>
<div class="SR_box">
    <div class="SR_title">
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <a class="SR_box_fs fa fa-arrows-alt" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <iframe class="iframe" src=<%= "#{x['link']}"%> sandbox="allow-same-origin, allow-top-navigation, allow-forms"></iframe>
</div>
<% end %>
```

When I get / all is OK, but when execute the search nothing happens, and the browser show just the form without the frame created in ssearch.erb. Why?
Just the prompt show me a server error message that say:

> http://localhost:4567 -> /ssearch
>   NoMethodError - undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass:
>   ssearch.erb:2:in 'block in singletonclass'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH oh oh, the problem was easy (now).

Sinatra don't accept variable in 'data:' parameter in jquery ajax request, you have to write explicity in this way (in my case):

```
data: { term: form.find("input[name='key']" ).val()},
```

while before wrote:

```
 term = form.find( "input[name='key']" ).val(),
...
data: term,
```

then i modify a little the .rb file in this way:

```
 @keyword = params[:term]
    puts "keyword is  #{@keyword}"
    @items = extract_cse_info(@keyword)
   puts @items

    erb :ssearch, :layout => false
```

Now i'm in the seven heaven, and i love to be a newbie for this kind of emotion :)

bye